# Prevent retain cycle in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, retain-cycle, retaincount

I have the following class in my project, I am wondering if this implementation will end up doing retain cycle

```
public final class CalendarService: AccessTokenProvider {

  internal var accessToken: Observable<AccessToken> = ... 

  private let transport: CalendarTransport

  public init(factory: ServiceTransportFactory) {
    self.transport = factory.calendarServiceTransport()
  }

  func getCalendar() -> Observable<GCalendar, NSError> {
    return self.accessToken.prefix(maxLength: 1).flatMapLatest(self.transport.getCalendar)
  }
}
```

my question is the `self` in the `flatMapLatest` will create a retain cycle? also what if I do this too:

```
func getCalendar() -> Observable<GCalendar, NSError> {
  let methodRef = self.transport.getCalendar(token:)
  return self.accessToken.prefix(maxLength: 1).flatMapLatest(methodRef)
}
```

Comment: Did you try to profile Leaks? That's the fastest way to check your implementation.

Comment: Finding Retain Cycle With Instruments:
https://samwize.com/2016/05/30/finding-retain-cycle-with-instruments/

Comment: Method references implicitly capture `self` (which is clearly necessary, because the method needs an instance to work with!)